# Primefaces tooltip com imagem e filtro em tabela

Tags: primefaces, datatable, filter, tooltip, image

Olá

Tenho a seguinte situação: uma tabela de usuários, e os usuários possuem fotos, gostaria de ao passar o mouse em cima do nome do usuário, apresentar um tooltip do primefaces com a imagem do usuário, que já está acontecendo.

O problema surge quando filtramos os dados da tabela, após filtrar a imagem não aparece mais.

Observações:

- A imagem está sendo inserida através de um objeto StreamedContent.
- Pelo que pesquisei algumas pessoas estão relatando ter problemas com o filtro sendo setado null, dessa forma ao filtrar, perde a referência dos dados, mesmo assim não consegui solucionar o problema, segue o link do possível problema: http:/forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44524

Mesmo seguindo os passos citados, não funcionou pra mim, no entanto acredito que este seja o problema.

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

[image: Imagem exemplificando o problema]

```html
<p:dataTable id="tableUsers" var="userTable" value="#{usersController.listUsers}" selection="#{usersController.selectedUsers}" filteredValue="#{usersController.filteredUsers}" rowKey="#{userTable.id}">
  
  <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{usersController.onFilterTable}" />

  <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{userTable.id}" filterBy="#{userTable.id}" filterMatchMode="exact">
    <h:outputText value="#{userTable.id}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{userTable.name}" filterBy="#{userTable.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputLink id="content" value="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
      <h:outputText value="#{userTable.name}" style="z-index:1;" />
    </h:outputLink>
    <p:tooltip id="toolTipContent" for="content" position="bottom">
      <p:graphicImage id="imageThumbnail" cache="false" rendered="#{userTable.imageStreamed != null}" value="#{userTable.imageStreamed}" width="80" height="80" stream="false" />
      <h:outputText rendered="#{userTable.imageStreamed == null}" value="Sem foto" />
    </p:tooltip>
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Ao filtrar a tabela

```js
public void onFilterTable(FilterEvent filterEvent) {
  System.out.println("Dados da pesquisa (filtro):");
  Set < String > keys = filterEvent.getFilters().keySet();
  for (String key: keys)
    System.out.println("Chave: " + key + " - Valor: " + filterEvent.getFilters().get(key));

  System.out.println("");
  List < Users > listFilteredUsers = (List < Users > ) filterEvent.getData();
  System.out.println("Lista de Usuários Filtrados: " + listFilteredUsers);
  if (listFilteredUsers != null)
    for (Users user: listFilteredUsers)
      System.out.println(user.getName() + " - StreamedContent: " + user.getImageStreamed());

  System.out.println("=================================================================");
  System.out.println("");
}
```

Com o código acima obtenho o seguinte no console

[image: Console]

Como vocês podem notar, a primera consulta ele retorna null (não sei o porque, pois é uma consulta válida, e na tela retorna o dado normalmente, só no Java que não)

Depois desse primeiro null, todos os outros dados são retornados mas sempre em atraso, por exemplo, quando é feito uma pesquisa que deveria retornar dois usuários, não retorna nada, quando faço outra pesquisa, retorna os dados da anterior e assim por diante, mas isso apenas no Java, na tela a pesquisa funciona normalmente (fiquei sem entender isso, no back-end o evento filter me retorna algo e na tela acontece outro).

Comment: O valor de `userTable.imageStreamed` muda ou permanece o mesmo ?

Comment: Permanece, mas em atraso, vou explicar melhor na questão.